# duplicate error in migrating on rails with activeadmin and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I'm trying to install activeadmin on rails with devise.
I added gemfile and ran

```
rake db:migrate
```

and i met these errors.

```
== 20170821153121 DeviseCreateAdminUsers: migrating ===========================
-- create_table(:admin_users)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "admin_users" already exists: CREATE TABLE "admin_users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "encrypted_password" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "reset_password_token" varchar, "reset_password_sent_at" datetime, "remember_created_at" datetime, "sign_in_count" integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, "current_sign_in_at" datetime, "last_sign_in_at" datetime, "current_sign_in_ip" varchar, "last_sign_in_ip" varchar, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:137:in `execute'
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the error is fairly self explanatory, your database already has a table with the same name Devise/Active Admin wants to use and table names must be unique.

Did you already at some point already use/try the activeadmin gem? If you already created the tables for it, trying to create and execute new migrations will fail, but you should be able to either just use those, or delete them and make fresh ones.

Or does your application just happen to have a `AdminUser` model for its own use? If it does one of them has to change.

You should be able to see either case in your `db/schema.rb`, or in the old migrations in `db/migrations/`. If you tried deleting/reverting a migration by just deleting its migration without script without rolling back first (either `rails db:rollback` or a DB backup), you may also have old tables actually in the DB, which you may want to manually delete.

If you do need to rename the Active Admin tables, the advice given in Github [Database tables name prefix #4960](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4960) is to manually edit the migration and use `self.table_name=` in the models to tell them the new names.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error it self repeat that you have already the same table called "admin_users".

Please run the command on rails console to see your already created tables like this way:

> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables

If you would find same table in the list then you need to delete that table manually or another way is just drop your db and recreate it after that you can able to run your new migration.